# ActionCable channel doesn't connect unless page is reloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, actioncable

I have a cable that works great if I manually refresh the page, but if I navigate to it, it never starts streaming.

WHen working correctly, I see this in the Rails console:

```
ChecklistPdfChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ChecklistPdfChannel is streaming from checklist_pdf_2-5a-ntiasohen-gattopuin
```

Here's the coffeescript:

```
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->
  if !App.presence
    App.presence = App.cable.subscriptions.create({
      channel: 'ChecklistPdfChannel',
      issueable_id: window.location.pathname.split('/').splice(2,1).toString()
    },
      connected: ->
      disconnected: ->
      received: (data) ->
        console.log(data)
        $('#pdf_status').html "#{data.html}"
  )
return
```

I've tried the following:

- added meta tag: `<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">`
- added `'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'` on the asset calls in the layout

the behavior is the same in both development and staging/production (Heroku).

Rails 5.2.2, ActionCable 5.2.2, Turbolinks 5.2.0

Comment: add `data-no-turbolink` like `<%= link_to('Giraffe', @giraffe, 'data-no-turbolink' => true) %>` to the links that navigate to the pages with ActionCable.

Comment: Unfortunately this persists even with `data-no-turbolink`. I have to reload the page in order for the cable channel to be active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way I was able to get this to work was to add this meta tag on the pages where I needed the cable active:

```
<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
```